# cron won't run PHP because of forward slash

Tags: php, cron

Alright, so I've got a cron job that is supposed to run a PHP file every minute, I'm hitting the file and getting an error that I'm not sure how to fix exactly; the server (Debian) will not recognize PHP's include if there is a '/' located anywhere in the link.

I've been searching for an answer for this for about an hour and a half and keep running up nothing. Hopefully you guys could lend me a hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use absolute file path. If the "include" files are relative to the "main.php", you can use

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/mysubdir/myincfile.php");
```

The more elegant way about filesystem "slashes" is to use **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR**, eg,

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."mysubdir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."myincfile.php");
```

The better yet way to handle directories is to "define" them:

```
if(!defined('MYROOTDIR'))
{ 
   define('MYROOTDIR',(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."mysubdir"));
}
include(MYROOTDIR."myincfile.php");
```

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: I actually have  my directories defined, i just hadn't run into any issues until the Cron job.

This fixed it though, thank you sir!